# How to prove $d_{\delta^{\epsilon}(f)}(\alpha)=\epsilon^{-n}d_{f}(\alpha)$?

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

This appears in Grafakos book  Lorentz spaces?
How to prove $d_{\delta^{\epsilon}(f)}(\alpha)=\epsilon^{-n}d_{f}(\alpha)$?
where $\delta^{\epsilon}(f)(x)=f(\epsilon x)$,$d_{g}(\alpha)=\mu\{x:|g(x)|>\alpha\}$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

By definition we have $d_{\delta^{\epsilon}(f)}(\alpha)=\mu\{x:|\delta^{\epsilon}(f)|>\alpha\}=\mu\{x:|f(\epsilon x)|>\alpha\}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\chi_{\{x:|f(\epsilon x)|>\alpha\}}dx$ How to transformation?
Any hints are wellcome!!!

Comment: Hint: By the change of variable formula: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\chi_{\{x:|f(\epsilon x)|>\alpha\}}\,dx=\epsilon^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\chi_{\{x:|f(x)|>\alpha\}}\,dx\,.$

Comment: Thank you Kurt G. ! your hint is very helpful, but why not $\epsilon^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\chi_{\{\frac{x}{\epsilon}:|f(x)|>\alpha\}}(\frac{x}{\epsilon})dx?$

Comment: I think you just wrote the same in yet another unusual notation. To me their notation $d_{\delta^{\epsilon}(f)}(\alpha)=\epsilon^{-n}d_{f}(\alpha)$  is a perfect example of making simple things look complicated. Anyway: it can only be the change of variables formula and nothing else. Take $n=1$ and a concrete $f$ where you can calculate something explicitly.

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\chi_{\{x:|f(\epsilon x)|>\alpha\}}\,dx$ is the Lebesgue measure of the set where the function $g:x\mapsto |f(\epsilon x)|$ is larger than $\alpha\,.$ Take $n=1$ and $f(x)=1/\sqrt{|x|}\,.$ Then
$$
\{g>\alpha\}=\{x:\sqrt{|\epsilon x|}<\alpha^{-1}\}=\{x:|x|<\alpha^{-2}\epsilon^{-1}\}\,.
$$ 
The Lebesgue measure of this is $2\alpha^{-2}\epsilon^{-1}$ and this is $\epsilon^{-1}$ times the Lebesgue measure of $\{f>\alpha\}\,.$

Comment: thank you Kurt.G!!!! I get it.